# NERDTree Directory listing disappear after I open a file in mvim

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

I am having trouble configuring NERDTree plugin in mvim. Whenever I open a directory in mvim, NERDTree is getting loaded perfectly. But whenever I try to open a new file from NERDTree window, the file is opening in a new buffer and the NERDTree directory listing is disappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this  to your `.vimrc`

```
let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 0
```